# How to create directories in a ROS launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, extract-images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to create a directory in a ROS launch file in order store images in the specified folder.
How can this be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188298/how-to-create-directories-in-a-ros-launch-file/) by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2014-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked before in this [Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/150286/can-i-make-a-directory-in-launch-file/).
See my answer there, there is a quite hacky way of actually doing what you request.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2